# Time zone problem in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, timezone

I have set the default time zone like `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`

But the time is exactly 4 hrs advance. 
(ie) if Current time is `6:00:00` then its saving as `10:00:00`

Don't know whats wrong. Its working perfectly in `localhost` but not in `godaddy` server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried asking godaddy? I'm fairly sure date_default_timezone_set is a native PHP function and not related explicitly to CodeIgniter:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php